# $ \frac{dy}{dx}= -\left( \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+3y}\right)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Find the solution of the differential equation:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= -\left( \frac{\sin(x+y)}{x+3y}\right)$$

My attempt:
The equation can be simplified into

$$\sin(x+y)\text{dx}+(x+3y)\text{dy}=0$$

This is in thw form of $$Mdx+Ndy=0$$
Where $M=\sin(x+y),N=(x+3y)$

This equation is not exact and I'm unable to find any integrating factor to this question.

How can i find the solution to this differential equation?!

Comment: This is some weird looking ODE. That sine will be difficult to separate. What is the source of the problem?

Comment: @Vasili i think it is a csir problem. I'm given this question in class